# What are the benefits of async webservices when not all parts of the code is async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, servicestack, asp.net-web-api

I am wondering how much benefit you get from using async http requests if not all parts of your code is async.

Lets consider to scenarios: 1) async http requests blocking on sync database calls, and 2) sync http requests awaiting async database calls.

1) Web Api supports async action methods, but if I do a sync database call when handling the request, then the thread blocks on the call, and I will not get the benefits of better thread economy that async could give me or what?

2) If I have a synchronous ServiceStack service call that awaits an async database call, then what happens? I assume a thread is reserved for handling the entire sync http request, and when this thread awaits an async call then it is still reserved to the web request or what ?

Basicallly my question can be boiled down to this: Is there any reason to use async if not all IO calls are async?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the server side, there is usually no benefit in a partially-`async` solution.

> 1) Web Api supports async action methods, but if I do a sync database call when handling the request, then the thread blocks on the call, and I will not get the benefits of better thread economy that async could give me or what?

Correct. As soon as you do a synchronous (blocking) database call, you are tying up a thread for the duration of that call. So the benefits that you would have gotten from `async` do not apply.

> 2) If I have a synchronous ServiceStack service call that awaits an async database call, then what happens? I assume a thread is reserved for handling the entire sync http request, and when this thread awaits an async call then it is still reserved to the web request or what ?

This is just the same as a synchronous database call. Under the covers, a synchronous database call executes the actual call asynchronously and then blocks the calling thread until it completes. So you still have a thread blocked for the duration of the call, and you don't get any `async` benefits.

> Basicallly my question can be boiled down to this: Is there any reason to use async if not all IO calls are async?

There are a few more obscure scenarios. You can use `Task.WhenAll` to do a limited type of concurrency, which is much easier with `async` than other forms of asynchronous concurrency. But that's the only benefit I can think of if you don't have a fully-`async` stack.

Answer (score 3):

It basically boils down to what the calling code can do while the async call is being done.  Your first example is a good fit for this.  The UI can go about doing other things when a save method is called.  It doesn't matter what is going on behind the scenes within the method...control has been given back to the application to continue about its way.

Your second example just means that the servicestack service *could* do something while the async database call is being done.  But if it isn't doing anything, there isn't any real reason to use an async call to begin with.

What the async method does during its workload is not as important as what the calling application *can* do during the call.

Comment: Josh, your comment does not really address the OP's question. He was asking about using async model on the service side, your answer (at least the first paragraph) refers to reasons to use async on the client side.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin The first and last sentences are by far the most important in this answer.  They cover the general case, and they are quite correct.

Comment: Yes, as @EkkostikMartin writes I am interested in the server side. The reason I am asking is because I am interested in using async as a way to create scalable webservices, because the webserver will require  less threads to handle many requests if no thread blocks.

Comment: @Servy - I disagree. WebApi's async model is beneficial to improving server performance by not blocking the executing thread and relieving pressure on the IIS threadpool. AJAX (for example in web) takes care of what the calling application can do, and this doesn't require an async enabled web method.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin The point there is that the async method is useful because there is a thread that is, instead of doing a blocking wait, going off and doing productive work.  If the construct of the server is such that even using an asynchronous IO method results in the main thread just doing a blocking wait on all async tasks, at some level, then you're not really gaining anything.  To use the common phrase, you need to "async all the way up" to get anything out of it.  It's just that, in this case, the "top" is the main entry point for the server, and everything "above" that doesn't matter.